# Drupal: Display variables in an embedded node

Tags: drupal

I want to know if there's a way to print an undefined variable in the body of a node, with PHP input filter, something like:

```
<?php
print $foo;
?>
```

And then, in another node define the values of the variables in the body, like:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
?>
```

and embed the previous node in it with PHP or other method and print in it the variables defined in the including node.

Answer (score 1):

Putting php code in node body fields is **never** the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [php filter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/php_filter/6) processes the code by calling [`drupal_eval()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_eval/6), a wrapper around the standard php eval() function. From the linked documentation:

> Using this wrapper also ensures that
>   the PHP code which is evaluated can
>   not overwrite any variables in the
>   calling code, unlike a regular eval()
>   call.

So your attempt would not work - and I strongly agree with googletorp that this would be a bad idea anyways.

Comment: Indeed, a good answer might be investigating the creation of your own input filter (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_filter/6).